# CSS - use character for list marker

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Using CSS, how can I set a character like "►" as a list marker for an HTML list?

Comment: I believe you're going to have to turn it into an image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the hex value of the desired character in CSS like this:

```
ul li:before { 
   content: "\25BA";  /* hex of your actual character, found using CharMap */
}
```

*Note:* this will not work in IE < 8

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/5yKBq/

To add a space after the bullet: `content: "\25BA" " ";`
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/5yKBq/1/)

You can also use an image like this:

```
ul {
   list-style: disc url(bullet.gif) inside;
}
```

Comment: [Also work using the character itself](http://jsfiddle.net/cEpPs/1/), although you might run up to encoding problem.

Comment: @Kraz: True, that's why I didn't mention it. Its worth trying though.

Comment: You're probably better off with a `margin-right` on the `:before` if you want to adjust the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you need this in IE<8, you can use the following expression:

```
UL LI:before,
UL LI .before {
    content: "►"
    /* Other styles for this pseudo-element */
}

/* Expression for IE (use in conditional comments)*/
UL LI {
    list-style:none;
    behavior: expression(
        function(t){
            t.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<span class="before">►</span>');
            t.runtimeStyle.behavior = 'none';
        }(this)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not very friendly with Behaviors, expressions, htc files, !important rule, hacks, using tables for non-tabular data, etc.

Comment: The expressions, actually, not that bad. If you'd use `one-time-run` overwriting the property where the expression is, and also place the functions for expressions in a `.js` file, it become a great way to fix a lot of problems in IE.